How to expand function calls imported from other modules using a Javascript bundler?
This is kind of strange requirement, but is it possible to expand functions calls inline by using a Javascript bundler or some other technology? I have zero experience with bundlers, but this is what I am looking for:
Suppose there are two file:
// print.js
export function showMessage(message) {
    console.log(message)
}

// hello.js
import { showMessage } from "./print.js"
export function hello(name) {
    showMessage(`Hello, ${name}`)
}

Is there a way to produce a file (say bundle.js) from hello.js that will export the hello function but looks something like this:
// bundle.js
export function hello(name) {
    (function (message) {
        console.log(message)
    })(`Hello, ${name}`)
}

I want to do this so that I can import the hello function in another file and pass it along to the Selenium's executeScript function. Something like:
import { hello } from "./bundle.js"
driver.executeScript(hello, 'Jane')


Does selenium executeScript not support nested function calls?

@RahulR. It has signature of WebDriver.executeScript<any>(script: string | Function, ...args: any[]): Promise<any>. So if I pass it a function it will only send its body to the browser, and ignore everything that's outside the body of the function.

in order to import anything the browser would need to know the script is a module.  That might require modifying the DOM. (not sure that could actually work... might not be evaluated) There should not be a need for this though... just include everything in the executeScript call.  (I believe it has it's own scope)    The IDE is your friend when it comes to formatting/escaping large strings.  (copy/paste into string myJSString = "....)

@browsermator I would rather not write everything in the executeScript call. That breaks D.R.Y. Also, I am not looking for alternate solutions.
